# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR SSH

Tags: php, parsing, ssh

I wrote a php script that use simple_html_dom to parse a website infos.
Its a big script and when I try to run it on my browser the script works but Time out before to end.. 
When I try using SSH I get this error:

> Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in .... on line 30

line 30:

```
$titlevar = explode('for &euro;', $element->find('a[class="title-link"]', 0)->plaintext);
```

Whats wrong with my code ?
PS: I thought it was a problem with my php version so I tried to rename my file to .php5 but still not working...
I changed my .htaccess to enable php5 but still when I use php -v it shows me PHP 4.4.9.

**EDIT:**

I had to run my script with this:

> php5.4 script.php

Comment: Why are you still using an ancient PHP version? PHP 4.4.9 was released almost 5 years ago. You should upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: On my hosting settings PHP is set to 5 but whith SSH it shows me 4.4.9

Comment: Then ask your hosting provider to upgrade the CLI version of PHP to match the Webserver version

Comment: I had to run my script with this: php5.4 script.php > Thanks, worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to access CLI php with a modern version, you can execute the script through the webserver by using something like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to run it through the webserver. Might want to set it up to run through *localhost* in that case.

Answer (score 0):

PHP4 doesn't allow method chaining which you're doing with `$element->find('a[class="title-link"]', 0)->plaintext`.

Also, simple_html_dom requires PHP5 so even if you fix the syntax error you'll still get function or class does not exist errors after.